# Create product viewable by only specific customer or customer group

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

I want to add a product that can be viewed only by a specific customer or group of customers via Rest API

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: To achieve this functionality either you have to implement custom module or have to buy extension

Comment: could u specify how to do it or extension name

Comment: You can use this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/fme-restrictcustomergroup.html

Comment: @Mitro thx but this is done manually but what i want is via rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this idea helps you to achieve the goal.

1. Create a Custom **Product MultiSelect/Select Attribute** which will be having **Customer Groups** as the options.
2. Now you need to customize the Product Collection Factory by adding a filter to added Custom **Product MultiSelect/Select Attribute**. You need to check the current customer group & product customer group.

Comment: but it has to be done via Rest API. the second part customer group is optional first have to stop display to other customers beside customer for whom it was created via REST API